# You can have [anydesk] you like, but not here

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across the [anydesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anydesk) tag on a question that was (incorrectly) in the Help and Improvement queue and it appears to be a candidate for burnination and deleting all of the tagged questions.

This tag has 10 questions, the first of which dates from July last year. It has no description in the tag wiki.

Looking at the criteria for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
The questions do relate to the remote desktop product, AnyDesk. It is unambiguous.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
AnyDesk does have [APIs](https://support.anydesk.com/REST-API), so it is possible that software development questions regarding this product could be asked, but [the company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AnyDesk) has been around since 2014, and no on-topic questions have yet been asked under this tag.
The vast majority of the questions are *General Computing* questions which should be on SuperUser if anywhere. One, closed, programming [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357393/how-to-block-remote-viewer-appslike-anydesk-from-viewing-my-app-on-android) remains (and I removed the tag from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340898/how-to-hide-android-application-from-remote-device-access-like-teamviewer)) but they were both incorrectly (IMO) tagging [anydesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anydesk) as an example of the sort of program they didn't want to be able to access their app. They had no specific connection to AnyDesk.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
As all of the questions are off-topic, for example:

- [Unable to install of AnyDesk due to dependency errors in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61343609/unable-to-install-of-anydesk-due-to-dependency-errors-in-ubuntu-17-04)
- [AnyDesk Cannot Connect to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60579306/anydesk-cannot-connect-to-server-please-check-your-internet-sever)
- [Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 4. anydesk: error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585500/ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-4-anydesk-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpolk)

I'd argue that it is not meaningful, and encourages off-topic posts. I did contemplate posting a tag-wiki update to explain what is and isn't on-topic, but looking at the similar tag [teamviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamviewer), it appears that having:

> Use this tag for specific programming questions about TeamViewer only. Questions about the general usage of the software are off-topic.

in the tag Wiki, doesn't really help. If API-related questions arise, perhaps that would be a good time to create the tag again, but until then I don't think it is necessary. Even [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/anydesk) doesn't have an [anydesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anydesk) tag, at present.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
Probably

Considering all of the above, I suggest that the [anydesk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anydesk) tag be burninated, and all associated questions be deleted/migrated as they are off-topic, with the possible exception of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357393/how-to-block-remote-viewer-appslike-anydesk-from-viewing-my-app-on-android), which could just have the tag removed. Most of the questions have answers, some accepted, so would not Roomba.